Automation of custom tables
I am using the same format for all latex tables in my book, and I would like to type less everytime.
I would like to create a newenvironment in order to type
\begin{mytable}{|c|c|c|}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{mytable}

and automatically have (no matter the amount of columns or rows of the table) the table with hline at the top, at the bottom and between everyrow, and only the first row being textbf{} for everycolumn.
I've managed to make the firstrow rowcolor{blue!100} with chatgpt, but I couldn't fix the hline problem or textbf for the entire first row.
Thanks!

Do the tables need captions and, if so, labels too?

Yes, if possible

The code below loads the environment's contents and massages it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytable}{O{\rowcolor{blue!30}}mb}
 {% #1 = \rowcolor, #2 = number of columns, #3 = body
  \facuoz_mytable:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__facuoz_mytable_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_seq
\seq_new:N \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_bold_seq
\tl_new:N \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \facuoz_mytable:nnn
 {
  % separate the rows
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__facuoz_mytable_rows_seq { \\ } {#3}
  % check for a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__facuoz_mytable_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_tmpa_tl
   {% last item not empty, add it back
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__facuoz_mytable_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  % separate off the first row
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__facuoz_mytable_rows_seq \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_seq { & } \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_tl
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_bold_seq \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_seq
   { \textbf{##1} }
  % print the table
  \begin{tabular}{|*{#2}{c|}}
  \hline
  % the first row
  #1 \seq_use:Nn \l__facuoz_mytable_firstrow_bold_seq { & }
  \\ \hline
  % the other rows
  \seq_use:Nn \l__facuoz_mytable_rows_seq { \\ \hline }
  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}{3}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{mytable}
%
\qquad
%
\begin{mytable}[\rowcolor{red!20}]{2}
1 & 2 \\
4 & 5 \\
7 & 8
\end{mytable}

\end{document}


Some notes.

I'm not sure how useful this is.
Caged tables are awful.
If you correctly use rules (no vertical ones and only the needed horizontal ones, see the manual of booktabs), boldfacing and coloring the first row isn't needed.


With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mytable } { O { } m O { } }
  { 
    \begin{NiceTabular}{#2}[hlines,#1,#3]
    \RowStyle[bold]{}
  }
  { \end{NiceTabular}}


\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}{|c|c|c|}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{mytable}

\end{document}



With the tabularray package, you could use the \NewTblrEnviron macro to create a new tabular environment:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytable}
\SetTblrInner[mytable]{
  hline{1,2,Z}={0.8pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{mytable}


\end{document}


